# How to auto duplicate row of data(non-values) for data entry form to change one field?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For my data entry spreadsheet, I have multiple rows of data(address, DOB, identifier,name) for the same person with only one field that's changing(delivery date). Since it is all in random locations(due to the disorganised way the hard copies were filled), how do I easily duplicate the row of data for the same person in a new row so that I only need to change only the delivery date?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have data e.g. like this:

```
john 1/1/1980 ID1 2/2/2021
andy 2/2/1981 ID2 3/3/2021
kate 3/3/1982 ID3 4/4/2021
```

Now you want to capture from hard copy, a new entry for e.g. andy. Everything stays the same except the last column.

**Shortcuts are your friend:**

```
Select any cell in the "andy" row.
Hit Shift Spacebar to select the whole row.
Hit CTRL c to copy the whole row
Hit CTRL + (+ key on the numpad or CTRL SHIFT = to get to the + via the = key) to "Insert copied cells" above the current row
Hit CTRL "right arrow" to jump to the last column
Hit F2 to edit the cell
```

If you are going to do this a LOT, you might want to consider recording the button presses with a macro (just search "how to record a macro in excel" on youtube). You can then assign a keyboard shortcut to that macro, so that everything happens with one key combo!